# nginx multiple route and different servers

Tags: nginx

I need to configurate SPA application on / and (admin|api|auth) to django proxy_pass using nginx, this is my curent nginx configuration settings :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log  off;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 750M;

    location ^~ /static/ {
        root /opt/youtubeapp;
        expires max;
        break;
    }

    location ^~ /media/ {
        root /opt/youtubeapp;
        expires max;
        break;
    }

    location ~ ^/(robots\.txt|favicon\.ico\.html)$ {
        root /opt/youtubeapp/static/;
    }

    location / {
        root /opt/bulkvideo-front;
        expires max;
        break;
    }

    location ^~ /(admin|api|auth) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4600/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

        # added 4 lines above. Remove or comment it if fail
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Authorization, Accept";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;

    }

}
```

my current configuration have one problem, when my SPA send request to  `http://localhost/auth/signin/` server return error messagge `Page not found` with `Request URL:  http://localhost/signin/`, Problem is nginx because not send complete route path, how i can fix this problem in nginx ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change this:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4600/;
```

To this:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4600;
```

Anything you add to a proxy_pass directive, even just a slash, will replace the part of the original request url which matches the location block.

Comment: Ha e you reloaded Nginx?